# Как один класс может реализовать разные интерфейсы?

Tags: java

Появился такой вопрос. Необходимо создать класс **Human** в двух вариантах. Первый вариант реализует интерфейс **Cavalry**, а второй реализует интерфейс **Infantry**. Экземпляры будут создаваться как: `Infantry warrior = new Human` / `Cavalry warrior = new Human`. Единственное различие между этими классами заключается в следующем: **Human** с типом **Cavalry** будет содержать в себе вложенный класс **Horse**, а с типом **Infantry** соответственно не будет. Вопрос: как это правильно реализовать? Заранее спасибо за советы.

Comment: Да тупо в объявлении класса указываете 2 интерфейса и реализуете их

Comment: А как я в таком случае могу реализовать вложенный класс для экземпляра с типом Cavalry, и не реализовывать вложенный класс для экземпляра с типом Infantry? Я имел ввиду, что мне нужно понять, с каким типом (Cavalry / Infantry) был создан экземпляр, что бы реализовывать/не реализовывать вложенный класс.

Comment: В вопросе внутреннее противоречие. Класс не может быть `в двух вариантах`. Можно создать класс, который будет реализовать и `Cavalry` и `Infantry`, но это будет означать, что каждый `Human` является и пехотинцем и кавалеристом.

Comment: Вероятно нужно изменить структуру классов. Опишите, как будут использоваться эти два вида объектов. Про различие вы уже написали, что у них разные поля. А в чем общность? В каких сценариях они будут использоваться подобным образом?

Comment: Так давайте разберемся. Это Java  и множественного наследия в нем нет. Есть его имитация с множественными интерфейсами. У вас один класс в задаче или несколько?

Comment: Класс Human будет один. Выражаться различие его экземпляров (Cavalry/Infantry) будет, например, при добавлении экземпляров в массив: `if (obj instanceof Cavalry) Cavaleries.add((Cavalry)obj);`. Общность заключается в том, что Human будет реализовывать интерфейс Unit, как и другие сущности. И у кавалериста, и у пехотинца будет метод strike.

Comment: А Cavalry и Infantry?

Comment: Это просто интерфейсы, необходимые для обозначения статуса юнита (Cavalry warrior = new Human).

Comment: Если это интерфейсы то они должны быть реализованы Human иначе как их выделить

Comment: мне кажется, что вы совсем неправильно смотрите на эту задачу. есть интерфейс unit, его имплементирует абстрактный класс human, от которого наследуются классы cavalry infantry. и тогда все понятно. вы уже на первом шаге нарисовали if (obj instanceof Cavalry). т.е. вы объявили интерфейс, чтобы привести к нему наследника, чтобы потом спросит у переменной типа интерфейса, а какой у тебя объект и закастовать. так может проще вообще не приводить ничего к интерфейсу, если вам тут же надо кастовать? вам не кажется это странным?

Answer (score 0):

Здесь Вам стоит обратиться к основам Java. Всё решается простым наследованием. При создании объекта "Human", даём ему дочерний класс "Cavalry" или "Infantry". К тому же это даёт Вам гибкость, например если вы захотите добавить ещё какой то класс, типо "artilleryСrew". Пример:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human human = new Cavalry();
        Human human2 = new Infantry();
    }
}

class Human {
}

class Infantry extends Human {

}

class Cavalry extends Human {
    class Horse {

    }
}
```